# Extracting certain portions of HTML from within PHP

Tags: php, web-crawler, html-parsing, simplexml, domdocument

Ok, so I'm writing an application in PHP to check my sites if all the links are valid, so I can update them if I have to.

And I ran into a problem. I've tried to use SimpleXml and DOMDocument objects to extract the  tags but when I run the app with a sample site I usually get a ton of errors if I use the SimpleXml object type.

So is there a way to scan the html document for href attributes that's pretty much as simple as using SimpleXml?

```
    <?php
    // what I want to do is get a similar effect to the code described below:

    foreach($html->html->body->a as $link)
    {
         // store the $link into a file
         foreach($link->attributes() as $attribute=>$value);
         {
              //procedure to place the href value into a file
         }
    }
?>
```

so basically i'm looking for a way to preform the above operation. The thing is I'm currently getting confused as to how should I treat the string that i'm getting with the html code in it...

just to be clear, I'm using the following primitive way of getting the html file:

```
<?php
$target      = "http://www.targeturl.com";

$file_handle = fopen($target, "r");

$a = "";

while (!feof($file_handle)) $a .= fgets($file_handle, 4096);

fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

Any info would be useful as well as any other language alternatives where the above problem is more elegantly fixed (python, c or c++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

Here's a bunch of code we use for a HTML parsing tool we wrote.

```
$target = "http://www.targeturl.com";
$result = file_get_contents($target);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
@$dom->loadHTML($result);

$links = extractLink(getTags( $dom, 'a', ));

function extractLink( $html, $argument = 1 ) {
  $href_regex_pattern = '/<a[^>]*?href=[\'"](.*?)[\'"][^>]*?>(.*?)<\/a>/si';

  preg_match_all($href_regex_pattern,$html,$matches);

  if (count($matches)) {

    if (is_array($matches[$argument]) && count($matches[$argument])) {
      return $matches[$argument][0];
    }

    return $matches[1];
  } else 

function getTags( $dom, $tagName, $element = false, $children = false ) {
    $html = '';
    $domxpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $children = ($children) ? "/".$children : '';  
    $filtered = $domxpath->query("//$tagName" . $children);

    $i = 0;
    while( $myItem = $filtered->item($i++) ){
        $newDom = new DOMDocument;
        $newDom->formatOutput = true;        

        $node = $newDom->importNode( $myItem, true );

        $newDom->appendChild($node);
        $html[] = $newDom->saveHTML();          
    }

    if ($element !== false && isset($html[$element])) {
      return $html[$element];
    } else
      return $html;
}
```

Comment: nice, i'll definitely give this a shot, need to look-up a few things but I think that won't be a problem now that I see what I need to look for

Comment: DOMDocument and DOMXPath is pretty awesome and extremely forgiving even for poor/broken HTML. There is loads that you can do with it :)

Comment: yeah, I've just started to experiment with the DOMXPath and it seams like fun. However i'm gonna need a deeper documentation then the one provided at php.net the examples aren't as informative as I'd want them to be.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `strpos($html, 'href=')` and then parse the URL. You could also search for `<a` or `.php`

Comment: I'd need something more elegant then that, the above solution by sonassi offers (as I see it) a more elegant solution to the problem, but thanks for trying :)